# How to get these outputs using these inputs?

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle

Examples of inputs and outputs:

**Input**: 3 7 20
**Output**: 1

**Input**: 17 2 1651
**Output**: 34

**Input**: 4 3 5
**Output**: 2

**Input**: 1000000000 1000000000 1000000007
**Output**: 49

**Input**: 27 37 100
**Output**: 99

Comment: Just clarifying: You looking for a single function f(i, j, k) that produces that output for each of these input sets?

Comment: @Graylocke Yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function is:

> f(a,b,c) = (a*b) %c
>   where % is the modulo operation

How:

> f(3,7,20) = 21%20 = 1
>  f(17,2,1651) = 34%1651 = 34
>  f(4,3,5) = 12%5 = 2
>  f(1000000000,1000000000,1000000007) = 10^18 % 1000000007 = 49
>  f(27,37,100) = 999%100 = 99